# calling slim api from javascript - cross origin request blocked

Tags: javascript, slim

I am trying to call a slim api from Javascript running on localhost and getting the error -
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://phoenixsoftware.co.nz/phoenixapi/api/clients. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
I am really confused about how to fix this. I have put the javascript and .htaccess file from web below:

Here is my javascript:

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'https://phoenixsoftware.co.nz/phoenixapi/api/clients', 
        type: 'PUT', 
            crossDomain: true,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(), 
        success: function(data) { 
                    alert (data);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);

        alert ("error"+textStatus+errorThrown);
   // report error
    }
 });
```

The htaccess file is as follows:
     RewriteEngine On

```
 # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
 # If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use one of the CORS middlewares.

Comment: Try adding this to your request 'headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}'

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType: "jsonp"`,

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/odm50dra/)

In the jsfiddle you may see alert from error block since I have commented the `data` But you may confirm status `200` from the network tab

Comment: thanks. Can you please let me know if other changes need to be made so that jsonp works the same as json - or does datatype json or jsonp work exactly the same ?